# CodeIgniter How to get all the fields names on which validation failed

Tags: validation, codeigniter-2

I want to find all the fields name on which validation failed.

I want to apply error class on the validation failed fields. I know how to display the error message related to the field.

But some how I want to know the field name such that I can check the weather field is there in the list and add an error class to that field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it depends on how you'll handle the results, but here's a function you can use to get the erroring fields :

```
print_r( $this->form_validation->error_array() )
```

If you need more, look at the /system/libraries/form_validation.php
From there you can find anything you want, including functions and variables names used/usable related to the lib.

Answer (score 9):

Kudos to **pit** for getting me started.  But I need to add this in case others have the same problem I did when using pit's answer.  In CI 2.0, I tried it and got :

```
Call to undefined method MY_Form_validation::error_array()
```

Since I hadn't intentionally tried to call anything from my custom form validation, I looked in /system/libraries/Form_validation.php.  At least in 2.0, there is no function error_array().

So to fix it, if you don't already have one, create a file /application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php (case sensitive) and put in the following code:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function error_array(){
        return $this->_error_array; 
    }
}
?>
```

Then doing `print_r( $this->form_validation->error_array() )` will work.

Comment: What version do you use ? you should get it like in : https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out why you had it and I didn't.  The link you posted is the development branch, not the stable release.  Just pulled down 2.1.3 from http://codeigniter.com and confirmed it's missing from the stable zip.

Answer (score 0):

To set your own custom message you can either edit that file, or use the following function:

`$this->form_validation->set_message('rule', 'Error Message');`

Where rule corresponds to the name of a particular rule, and Error Message is the text you would like displayed.

If you include `%s` in your error string, it will be replaced with the "human" name you used for your field when you set your rules.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(array('field' => 'name','label' => 'Full Name','rules' => 'required'));
$this->form_validation->set_message('required', '%s Must be fill!');

echo validation_errors() //Full name Must be fill!
```

Comment: where does the $s comes from?